# updategram in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

i am new to Biztalk, am using 2006 R2.
Currently there is a online web form, which creates a record in a SQL Database, a column named Status is set to "Draft" within the web app.

The request is sent through Biztalk which creates reports, sends emails, outputs files in various formats.
I want to update the status through the various orchestration stages in BizTalk.
I was thinking of creating a new orchestration which is called from the main orch using a call orchestration shape.

So when the orch initialises the status is set to "Submitted", at any point an exception is caught, the status is set to "Failed" and if all ok set to "Processed"

For something this simple i was thinking an updategram, which i am new to.
Does this sound reasonable?
Also obviously i need to know what record i am updating.
Using the existing schema, what makes each submission unique is the combination of
Month, Year, Provider No and Interaction Type.
How can i achieve this in my where condition? is it something i need to do in a map?
any help appreciated.

rich

Answer (score 0):

You could resort to creating a [computed / calculated column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) containing the combined key (Month, Year, etc.).